# TreeListControl does not update values of children immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, devexpress

I use DevExpress. I have TreeListControl. One column consists Comboboxes (implemented by ComboBoxEditSettings) with several values. When I set a value in Combobox for parent its children will be updated just when I Change Focus or press Enter, but not immidiately.

Here are some Points I have already tried:

1. Set an Event in ComboBoxEditSettings for an interaction, eg MouseUp;
2. Set an EventToCommand for eventName EditValueChanged, for example.
   Binding is not working;
3. Set an Event on OkButton_Click, but I have
   not found how to get an OkButton_Click Event in Combobox.
4. Create CustomButton in ComboboxEdit and set a PopUpClose Event. In this
   case binding works, but I have not found how to set MyCustomButton
   the OkButton Event.

   Here is part of my Code. Maybe it helps to understand my case.

```
<dxg:TreeListControl x:Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Node"/>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Frequency"/>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn.EditSettings>                        
                   <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding Samplers}" IsTextEditable="False" DisplayMember="SamplerLongText" ValueMember="SamplerId">
<dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                        <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings/>
                          </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings.StyleSettings>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
                    </dxg:TreeListColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:TreeListColumn>
               </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
            <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
               <dxg:TreeListView                     
                    x:Name="TreeListView" 
                    AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" 
                    ShowTotalSummary="True"  
                    KeyFieldName="TreeItemId"                    
                    ParentFieldName="ParentId" 
                    ShowCheckboxes="true" 
                    CheckBoxFieldName="IsChecked"
                    IsCheckBoxEnabledFieldName="IsEnable"                 
                    AllowRecursiveNodeChecking="True" 
                    ShowNodeImages="True" 
                    AutoWidth="True"
                    ImageFieldName="NodeImage"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.View>           
        </dxg:TreeListControl>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have this little helper class for the exact same functionality when using CheckEdits but it should also work for your ComboBoxEdits.
Mind that it utilizes the EditValueChang**ing**-event under the hood which might already answer your question.

```
public partial class EditorCommitHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommitOnValueChangedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommitOnValueChanged", typeof(bool), typeof(EditorCommitHelper), new PropertyMetadata(CommitOnValueChangedPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetCommitOnValueChanged(GridColumn element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CommitOnValueChangedProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetCommitOnValueChanged(GridColumn element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(CommitOnValueChangedProperty);
    }

    private static void CommitOnValueChangedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridColumn col = source as GridColumn;
        if (col.View == null)
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<GridColumn, bool>((column, subscribe) => {
                ToggleCellValueChanging(column, subscribe);
            }), col, (bool)e.NewValue);
        else
            ToggleCellValueChanging(col, (bool)e.NewValue);
    }

    private static void ToggleCellValueChanging(GridColumn col, bool subscribe)
    {
        TreeListView view = col.View as TreeListView;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        if (subscribe)
            view.CellValueChanging += new CellValueChangedEventHandler(view_CellValueChanging);
        else
            view.CellValueChanging -= view_CellValueChanging;
    }

    static void view_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeListView view = sender as TreeListView;

        if ((bool)e.Column.GetValue(CommitOnValueChangedProperty))
            view.PostEditor();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="your header"
                FieldName="your_field"
                your_xmlns:EditorCommitHelper.CommitOnValueChanged="True">
</dxg:GridColumn>
```